# Is a repository or service provider required?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, service-provider, laravel-facade

I am building a Laravel 5.3 app that pulls data from a number of potential sources.  It's a fallback system with 3 sources:

- Database
- If not found, source 1
- If not found, source 2

All 3 sources are quite simple and will be accessed in the same way, by using the following 2 methods:

- `function get($id)`
- `function query($type, $string)`

I'm aware there is various terminology around the different ways to implement this, but I'm unsure after reading the docs what the cleanest approach is.  Should each data source be implemented as a `Repository`?  A `ServiceProvider` wrapped in a container?  I find the docs thorough but also lacking in overall/high level explanations, so any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: When you say if not found, does that mean if data not found or if source not found? If it's simply a failover system with the same protocol, you may consider not doing this at the application layer and using a load balancer instead

Answer (score 0):

The [Repository Pattern](http://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/More/Repository/README.html) is the following:

> Mediates between the domain and data mapping layers using a collection-like interface for accessing domain objects. Repository encapsulates the set of objects persisted in a data store and the operations performed over them, providing a more object-oriented view of the persistence layer. Repository also supports the objective of achieving a clean separation and one-way dependency between the domain and data mapping layers.

With that in mind, you can say that Eloquent itself is a much larger implementation of the Repository Pattern, but a Repository nonetheless. Since it's an ActiveRecord implementation, there isn't any real separation between the Repository and Storage mechanisms.

On to your question specifically, Laravel won't really cover the Repository Pattern itself in much the same way it doesn't cover Service classes or Singletons: It's not Laravel's responsibility to teach you these patterns, it's just giving you the means to organize these patterns more easily if you choose to implement them.

All that said, I would agree with you that each data source implement its own `RepositoryInterface`. From there, you can register your own [ServiceProvider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers) that in turn instantiates a custom Service Class whose purpose is to return the appropriate Repository.

If determining the appropriate Repository is light in logic, and is dependent only on the Controller responsible for the alternate data source, you can likely use [Contextual Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container#contextual-binding) and skip the Service Class altogether.

Either way, there's a few ways to skin this cat, but you're on the right track.

**Edit**: As an aside, if you want to strictly go "by the book" on this, you would probably want to separate out different Storage classes that connect to each data store separately, which you can then query as appropriate. Then your Repository - which is likely housing the same type of data collection regardless of its storage origins - can be responsible for the returned results.

Otherwise, if you want to stick with Eloquent as much as possible, you can look into [multiple data connections](http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections) to house each of your data sets.